# LEFT OUTER JOIN WITH WHERE CLAUSE MANY TO MANY IN SEQUELIZE

Tags: sequelize.js, feathersjs

I have a many to many relationship between two tables players and sports. With a bridge table playerSports containing the foreign keys of playerId and sportId. I need to query all the sports for a specific playerID he/she has not joined.

I am trying to use a left outer join in sequelize like this within feathersJS

```
      include: [
        {
          association: "players",
          required: false,
          attributes: ["id"],
          where: {
            id: context.params.user.id
          }
        }
      ]
```

Using the above code it returns all the sports whether joined or not but where the association is not present it returns null. Since I have to paginate I cannot filter afterwards and remove the ones with not null. So I get something like this.

```
id: 1
sportsStats: {...}
players: null


id: 2
sportsStats: {...}
players: [
{ id: 1,
  name: 'Ali' }
]
```

What I want to get is only the ones where player is null

```
id: 1
sportsStats: {...}
players: null


id: 3
sportsStats: {...}
players: null
```

Note: The players column will always have one since I am querying specific to a user.

I am trying to use a left outer join in sequelize like this.

```
  include: [
        {
          association: "players",
          required: false,
          attributes: ["id"],
          where: {
            id: context.params.user.id
          }
        }
      ]
```